# Find Quarter based on Weeks in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, week-number

I am trying to get the quarter in the year using calender class in Java. I am getting current date as below and use WEEK_OF_YEAR variable to get the week as below but below output is not making much sense to me as this week is not 3rd week in this year.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println("week of year: "+cal.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

output: 2014/02/17
week of year: 3
```

What i wanted to do is, i want to have below quarter (Currently Quarter1 is running and next Quarter is Quarter2) as result and use this on my application.

```
Quarter1 is from Week 1 to Week 12.
Quarter2 is from Week 13 to Week 24.
Quarter3 is from Week 25 to Week 37.
Quarter4 is from Week 38 to the end of the year.
```

Please help me with this and let me know how do i find out Quarters as mentioned above.

Comment: Quarters have nothing to do with weeks, they merely divide the twelve months of the year.

Comment: @skiwi Actually, quarters can be anything you want. Various industries and professions have variously defined quarters for various financial, legal, or other reasons. I've seen quarters that are practically arbitrary, having no connection to months *or* weeks. Months are clearly defined, and [ISO 8601 clearly defines week-of-the-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), but I'm unaware of any wide-ranging standard for quarters.

Answer (score 7):

`Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` is a constant. You wanted `cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`.

However, you should note that "week of year" is not as simple as you might expect, as a concept. For example, it can be 53 on January 1st, which belongs to the previous week-year in some years. Are you happy for the first quarter of a year to start later than January 1st?

(Unless you *really* need to use a week-year/week-of-week-year/day-of-week representation for business purposes, year/month/day is *much* easier to get your head around.)

If you *do* need to translate the week-of-year into a quarter after reading those caveats, you can just use:

```
public static int getQuarter(Calendar calendar) {
    int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    return weekOfYear < 13 ? 1
         : weekOfYear < 25 ? 2
         : weekOfYear < 38 ? 3
         : 4;
}
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is that notation? I've never seen the *ternary if* being used like that, but it all looks completely valid (and is) at the same time.

Comment: @skiwi: It's just multiple conditional operators, formatted in a way which makes the intention very readable (IMO). Some people like it and some hate it...

Comment: Yes. This is what i was looking for but have one more problem here for me. Once, i return querter1 using this function and if someone hit next button, i want to return Quarter2 and if screen has Quarter2 and someone hit next button, it should display next Quarter with year. Once we get Quarter1/2 from front end, how should i move to next Quarter. I can simply do Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3); with current time but that will not go to next year. Somehow i need to convert existing Quarter into cal obj and add 3 months to that. How should i do that?

Comment: @user3314492: it sounds like you need to add weeks, not months. After all, that's how you're defining your quarters. If that's not enough help, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861490/642706) is correct and should be accepted. With bonus points for that ternary sorcery. :-)

If you search StackOverflow, you'll find the more general question of determining quarters (and month, and weeks) asked and answered multiple times already. Also, search StackOverflow for "java week" to find helpful explanations about handling spans of time. Add "joda" to that search and you'll be even better off.

Keep in mind that time zone is critical, and that defines the first moment of day which defines first of month.

In [one answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773548/642706), I show how you can use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to get first of month, and then repeatedly add 3 months, if that is your definition of when quarters start.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime q1_2014 = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime q2_2014 = q1_2014.plusMonths( 3 );
…
```

Joda-Time offers 3 classes for defining spans of time that may be of use to you: Period, Duration, and especially, [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html).

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime yearStart = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
Interval q1 = new Interval( yearStart, yearStart.plusMonths( 3 ) );
Interval q2 = new Interval( q1.getEnd(), q1.getEnd().plusMonths( 3 ) );
…
boolean isNowInQ1 = q1.contains( DateTime.now() );
```

Interval uses the "half-open" approach to comparisons, meaning the start is inclusive and the end is exclusive. This is a sensible and useful approach to time spans.

Again, search StackOveflow for much more discussion and many examples.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. This is what i was looking for but have one more problem here for me. Once, i return querter1 using this function and if someone hit next button, i want to return Quarter2 and if screen has Quarter2 and someone hit next button, it should display next Quarter with year. Once we get Quarter1/2 from front end, how should i move to next Quarter. I can simply do Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3); with current time but that will not go to next year. Somehow i need to convert existing Quarter into cal obj and add 3 months to that. How should i do that?

Comment: @user3314492 Asking about handling "Next" button is an *entirely* new question which you should first research and, if necessary, post a new question. One hint: What you present in the user interface (view) and what you maintain as data behind the scenes (model) are two completely **separate things**. Search on "MVC" (Model-View-Controller) and do so reading; don't take any of it too seriously but it will give you ideas.